# Authentication problem-I can't enable my wireless driver

Tags: wireless, authentication

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 after trying it on a usb stick which worked fairly well.

But currently I am not able to install anything because every time I want to do something I'm prompted to enter a password and even when I provide the correct password I can't change anything!

Biggest problem is to activate the wireless driver! I could not enable the driver and I'm not able to connect to the internet now!

Please help me to deactivate the authentication.

Regards

Comment: In what way did you try "to do something"? Was that in the GUI or on the command line? The password you have to give is your own password.